# can httphandler fire an event?

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

I want to check Session in some pages. To do this I am adding the page names which I want to check inside web.config as a `appsetting` key.
I want to use httpHandler with firing an event after it finds the session is empty or something else.

If I create httpHandler as a dll(another project) and add to a web site, can handler fire an event and web site capture it inside a web page?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

Your HttpHandler puts a value in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection telling if there was Session or not. Something like

```
HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("SessionWasThere") = true;
```

You create a BasePage that checks that value in the `Page_Load` event and raises a new event telling so:

```
public abstract class BasePage : Page {
    public event EventHandler NoSession;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e){  
        var sessionWasThere = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("SessionWasThere");
        if(!sessionWasThere && NoSession != null)
            NoSession(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In your page, you suscribe to that event:

```
public class MyPage : BasePage{

    protected override void OnInit(){
        NoSession += Page_NoSession;
    }

    private void Page_NoSession(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Web pages are processed by the Page handler. He could do something with a `HttpModule` in for instance `Application_PostAcquireRequestState`. Otherwise the suggestion to use a custom page class with a custom event sounds doable.